# Firestore statechanges() Angular doesnt return anything when there is no data

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am querying a firestore collection with some where(). After applying the filter there is no data match in the collection. In this situation the firestore doesnt return anything. I have a loading icon which I need to disable if there is no data returned on filtering.

I am using ngrx statechanges to query the data

````
           ofType(quoteActions.queryQuotes),
           withLatestFrom(this.salesFacade.getFilter$),
           switchMap(([action, filter]) => {
             let response = this.dfs.collection<IQuotesDataModel>('quotes', (ref) => { return 
              ref2.orderBy('createdDate', 'desc').limit(50);
               }).stateChanges()
               return response;
           }),
           mergeMap(actions => actions),```
````

Comment: It looks `ref2.orderBy` should be `ref.orderBy`.

Comment: the ref2 was a typo I have changed that to ref. Also the way it works is if there is no records to be returned it just returns a blank array with no actions. So I am checking if id the array has no elements and disabling the loading icon. Thanks